# Installing JDK and IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ Idea  don't understand the JDKk, so I can't define data structure such as collections, lists, and so on. I can run my project with NetBeans but I can run any project with Idea!

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to the issue. What's the exact error you get when try to run your application? What errors are showing in the editor? A screenshot or two might help.

Comment: All of data structures such as lists,collections and so on are undefined for idea.the error is:"java: javacTask: source release 1.6 requires target release 1.6". I think that JDK is unknown for Idea. But i don't know why i can run my project with Netbeans.If is it possible i can email my project to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your added comment indicating the error, the issue is you have a misconfiguration in your language level. Go to the *File > Project Structure > JDK* dialog @PeterLawrey  mentioned. You need to ensure that the JDK version is equal to or greater than the language level selected in the "Project Language Level" section. It sounds like you have an older version JDK defined than the language level. So IDEA is trying to, for example, compile to Java v1.6 (based on the language level setting) but you have a 1.5 JDK defined. Click the help button on that dialog for more information on setting those. In the same main dialog, click "Modules" on the right. For each module, on the "Sources" tab, make sure the Language level is set to "Use Project Language Level" and on the "Dependencies" tab the Module SDK is set to "Project SDK".

**Edit**

p.s. In the future, you should post the error message you are getting. Without it, people can't help you. That's one reason your question is getting down votes.

**Edit 2**

Here's a screenshot that may help:
[image: Project JDK Settings Dialog]

Comment: Thanks for your guide.Now, 4 JDK are installed on my PC.The versions are: jdk1.5.0,jdk1.6.0_17,jre1.5.0,jre6 and the Idea version is:IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4.Is it OK or no?wanna e-mail my code to test you on your PC?

Comment: You can have as many JDKs installed  on your PC as you want. You just need to select the one you need/want to use for your project. I recommend you download and install a Java 7 JDK, Java 6, 5 and 1.4 are all end of life. You just need to make sure the language level is less than or equal to the JDK version. That *will* solve the error. If still have issues, post a screenshot of the dialog I mention in my answer (by editing your post)and I can see what the issue might be. (No e-mails please.) Also once fixed, please remember to mark my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: How i can fix this problem with environment variable(at control panel)?ok, i promise you if your answer will be correct,will mark your answer.

Comment: You can't correct this problem in the control panel. It is a misconfiguration in your IDEA project settings. You have a higher language level version set than you do JDK version. An older JDK can not compile to a newer Java language level. It's that simple. If you want your project to use Java 6, then the language level should be 6 and the JDK set to a Java 6 or Java 7 JDK. It's that simple. Do you not understand the settings I am talking about? If you are still having problems, *please* post a screenshot so I can see what you are doing wrong. I can't help you any further without one.

Comment: How I can send a screen shot from my Idea to you?I want send a pic from my screen,but i don't know how:(

Comment: The post [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) will explain how to create a screenshot. Then the post [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) will tell you how to upload it. You'll need to edit your original post.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your JDK with

File -> Project Structure -> + -> JDK -> select your JDK.

Comment: I did it,but it's now work!